# Return all unique places matching search query from google cloud API / googleway

Tags: r, googleway

I need to get all the google maps data on every grocery store / market / convenience store in a specified area.

Using the `googleway` package, I can access the API and get up to 60 results (20 at a time).  However, what if there are more than 60 places that match my query?  In other words, how can I be sure I'm not missing anything?

Unfortunately you can't reprex this without an API key, sorry about that.

```
suppressPackageStartupMessages(require(tidyverse))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(require(googleway))

set_key("your key here")

#Center of Guilford County, NC:
guilford <- c(36.086046, -79.796661)


reslst <- lst()
last_token <- NULL



  for(i in 1:3) {

    res <- google_places(location = guilford, 
                         radius = 30000,
                         place_type = "grocery_or_supermarket",
                         page_token = last_token)

    results <- res$results

    Sys.sleep(time = 3)

    last_token <- res$next_page_token

    reslst[[i]] <- results %>% select(id, name, place_id, price_level, rating, user_ratings_total, types) %>% as_tibble() %>% add_column(iter = i)

  }

all_results <- bind_rows(reslst)
```

Comment: There is no error over 60, that's just the limit set by the google API.  If you keep going, you just get duplicate results.

Comment: May be you can check the `nrow(results)` in each step using a `while` loop and extend the `i` until there are still some rows.  I can't check it as I don't have a billing account

Comment: @akrun I've tried doing this - after 3 pages (60 results) google keeps giving a full list of results, but they are duplicates of the previous results.